# memory efficient android jpeg conversion

Tags: android, image, bitmap, jpeg

My code is as follows:

```
    public static byte[] compress(byte[] data, CompressFormat format, int quality)
    {       
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        try {
            bm.compress(format, quality, baos);
        } finally {
            bm.recycle();
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

I'm concerned about memory usage when the size of the original image is large.  After compress() is called but before recycle() is called the following are extant in memory:

1. The original uncompressed binary data (data).
2. The decoded bitmap (bm) with all its pixel data.
3. The compressed binary data (stored internally within baos).

Is there any functionality in base Android that could perform this decoding/encoding step without creating the intermediate Bitmap object?  Or am I worrying unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a choice but to load the Bitmap I think. But it's not a problem. If your image is huge, scale it down before loading it into memory.

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html