# Retrieving a jpg image via fileUri

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I need some help here. I was wondering if there is a way for me to retrieve a jpg photo object from a fileUri.

I'm basically consuming an API where the parameter required is a photo object (jpg).
There is no need for me to display or show anything as thumbnails etc.

Simply need to pass the jpg file into the API.

Some sample codes would greatly help!

Kindly assist :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about you API but If you can pass a bitmap then you can use this -

```
public static Bitmap getImagefromURL(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);  
    return img;
 }
```

Then you can convert the bitmap into jpg...
   [bmp to jp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144941/memory-efficient-android-jpeg-conversion)

Comment: i did it another way though. to change bitmap to Base 64 String. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve an image in Bitmap format
Convert Bitmap to bytes array
Convert bytes array to base64 string through encoding.

Pass the string in an api. Server would need to decode it back to image file.